# Custom scroll element in react-window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized, react-window

I would like to create virtualized list. I have 100 000 items, but only e. g. 20 items (depends on window height) will be rendered. When user scrolls, no new items will be added, it only changes the props to those that are off the screen. So user see still right items.

I am using [react-window](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window) library as alternative to [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized):

```
import { FixedSizeList as List } from 'react-window'
...

const items = new Array(100000).fill({ title: '' })

const Item = ({ index, style }) => (
    <div key={index} style={style}>
        Item number {index}.
    </div>
)

const PageView = () => (
    <div style={{ overflowY: 'auto', height: '100vh' }}>
        <AnotherComponent />
        <AnotherComponent2 />
        <List itemSize={50} height={300} itemCount={items.length}>
            {Item}
        </List>
        <AnotherComponent3 />
    </Scrollable>
)
```

In this situation, the root `div` is full-screen scrollable element and `List` is 300px height also scrollable element. To remove scrolling from `List` I have to set height of `List` depends on count of items:

```
<List itemSize={50} height={items.length * 50} itemCount={items.length}>
```

Now scrolling is fine (scrollable is only root `div`), however `List` render all 100 000 items at once time, because they fit in the height of the `List`. Is there any way to work with `List` with custom scrolling element (or window) like in this [react-virtualized example](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/WindowScroller) with `WindowsScroller` or I have to use `react-virtualized`?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out for a project I'm working on right now, out and to complicate it the window is it a child of an element that has a constrained width. oof